# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In windows phone 8 i created one chat application, in that if continually received more message at a time, an exception is thrown at App.xaml.cs file .

how to solve this.or any way to find when and where the issue is happened.

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
>
> Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

[image]

Comment: Handle the exception, you know what causes the issue, so safeguard it and handle appropriately. Without any code it isn't really possible to help.

Comment: Fair chance that it is a threading issue. Got any background workers writing directly to the UI, two threads accessing the same list at the same time or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This error message is displayed when the memory is corrupted.

It may be your app that corrupts the memory, or it is also possible the corruption is caused by an issue in system.

Are you able to create a minimal test case and post here?